# Migrating a directory to a different svn repository

Tags: svn, migration

I have code in an svn repository, call it repository A. Now say that I need to move the contents to repository B, but repository B has already been active for a while for other projects. Is it possible to move a particular directory from repository A to repository B, preserving the file history? Normally, to migrate an entire repository to a new server, I would do:

```
svnadmin dump -r 0:179 rep_a > rep_a.dump
svnadmin create rep_b
svnadmin load rep_b < rep_a.dump
```

However, this acts on the whole repository and assumes repository B is empty to start with (I think). I can of course export the directory in question and import it into repository B, but I lose the version history.

Is there an easy way to move a particular directory from A to B without losing the version history?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you want to copy directory `trunk/project` of `rep_a` into `rep_b`, you have to use this command:

```
svnadmin dump rep_a | svndumpfilter include trunk/project | svnadmin load rep_b
```

The revisions related to `rep_a` will be added to the history of `rep_b`.

Be careful with that and make a backup before, of course. Also, it can be tricky if you have common directories, then you will have to remove directory creations from the dump (to avoid creating the same directories twice).

Comment: Thanks! So I presume the path to the directory is the same, so trunk/project on rep_a becomes trunk/project on rep_b? Just in case, is there an easy way to change the path during the migration? So that for example trunk/project becomes trunk_import/project?

Comment: There is an option `svnadmin load --parent-dir`. If you need something more complex, I suggest you have a look at this old Perl script (if you have a Perl interpreter): http://www.coelho.net/svn-merge-repos.html. There is another one in Python, but I have never used it except to make a few simple tests: http://www.orcaware.com/svn/wiki/Svnmerge.py

Comment: Does this work with the repository which is a dead? Can you check and respond here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523774/importing-older-code-with-revision-history-to-a-new-svn-repository

Comment: Can't answer at your link, question closed. But yes, in a way. The `svnadmin` command does not communicate with an SVN server but acts directly on the repository files - it must be issued on the server or with an access to the server's file system. So if your server is not running but you know where the SVN repositories are (on the disk) and can access them, you're fine. You must make sure the version of svnadmin is compatible with the server's though, don't use an older version.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Filtering Repository History](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.filtering) in the SVN book.