# Importing older code with revision history to a new SVN repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn, svn-repository

I have a code checkout from an SVN repository which is now not working, so original SVN server is now down.

And we have some local changes into SVN which is yet uncommitted.

How can I move the existing code available to us with revision history to the newly created SVN repository?

Any idea would be great to begin!

Answer (score -1):

Unlike git, svn doesn't store the complete history with each checked out copy. This means the history is only stored on your not working server. So I'm afraid you have the following options:

- create a new svn repository based on your local copy and loose the history
- get the svn server working again and keep the history
- switch to git (like 1st option) and avoid the problem in the future